# Angular js complex class

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to add a complex class to a div like this:

```
 <div class="{{'border-wrp'}} {{pageType}} {{borderStyleClass}} {{borderColourClass}}" > </div>
```

THanksss

Answer (score 1):

`ng-class` is used to add classes conditionally.

Like this

```
<div ng-class="{'yourclass':true,'yourclass1':false}"></div>
```

Comment: Yes, you can't use scope variable as class name.